# How to make and design our custom data table in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to add a table in my desktop app layout.but I'm in trouble that how to creat and add the data table using kivy language with kv file

Comment: as for me you have to do it in code, not in `kv` - especially adding data to table.

Comment: thanks sir, but how to design basic structure of table?

Comment: using Google: `kivy table widget`  I found [DataTable in KivyMD](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/datatables/index.html). You can also use `grid` layout similar to this [example](https://github.com/Seg-mel/kivy_table_widget)